# Why does the 20.04 LTS upgrade say "Do not install it"?

Tags: upgrade, 19.10, 20.04

I followed the [instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_or_19.10) to upgrade from Ubuntu 19.10 to the [final release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule) of 20.04 LTS—

1. Ensure that you have all updates installed.
2. Set "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" to "For any new version".
3. Run `update-manager -c -d`.

—and was greeted by this message:

> This release is still in development. Do not install it on production machines.

Why does it say this? What would happen if I continue anyway? I double-checked the instructions and there's no indication of how to handle this. I'm not sure if I should:

- ignore the warning and continue with the upgrade,
- take some action to resolve a problem on my end, or
- wait for a problem to be resolved externally.

### Details

- The message seems to be coming from [this file](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/DevelReleaseAnnouncement.html). There's an [analogous one](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement.html) with the messaging I'd expect. Maybe something is just showing me the wrong one?
- [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/409556/1859) (and later `DEBUG_UPDATE_MANAGER=1`) led me to the [release](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release) and [development release](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development) manifests, which link correspondingly to the two message variants. The release manifest doesn't include 20.04 LTS, which might help explain [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1229908/1859).
- That the upgrade instructions specify [`-d`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man8/update-manager.8.html) suggests that 20.04 LTS is indeed expected to be a development release. Perhaps I'm mistaken about what it means to be a final release (it's a type of development release?), or the project is simply running behind schedule?
- I asked about this in [#ubuntu](https://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2020/04/24/%23ubuntu.html#t22:52). A member of the Ubuntu Security Team confirmed that the omission from the release manifest is deliberate, to be changed "when 20.04 is a bit more stable and better tested". This is consistent with the hypothesis that 20.04 LTS is actually a development release, but contradicts the [release schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule) and [announcement](https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-20-04-lts-arrives).
- The mailing list [announcement](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2020-April/004969.html) says:

  > Users of Ubuntu 19.10 will be offered an automatic upgrade to 20.04 LTS
  >   via Update Manager *shortly*.
- [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1182583/1859) recounts precedent for delaying the update of the release manifest for a few days after the official release, and warns that bypassing the delay with `-d` constitutes an acceptance of risk as a tester.

Comment: I read somewhere that the upgrade from a previous version in only really supported once Canonical publishes the first point release (20.04.1)...

Comment: No; it draws a distinction between development and final releases, but doesn't explain why 20.04 LTS is being described as both. It documents special procedures for updating from 18.04 LTS, but not from 19.10.

Comment: We are end users as well as you and we don't know more than you. I think you should ask the developers at Canonical, and one way is via a bug report at Launchpad. Another way is to start a thread at [Ubuntu Discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/). Please post here if you get an answer over there.

Comment: I think you have found a bug in the release notes. `update-manager` should not require `-d` after release.

Comment: from lah7 Administrator https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-19-10-final-release-is-out/20275/10  "19.10's packages are in their final state, so it is safe to use update-manager -d to upgrade right away."